# Authentication issues for SharePoint online in desktop apps

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, office-365, authentication

I was working on a custom approval workflow for a site in SharePoint designer... at the point in the action when you designate the approver(s). Note that I am able to load the site and access most settings while in Designer. However, when I try to do a lookup to add a user I get an authentication window pop up.

[image]

When I enter my credentials the window just reappears and prompts for login again. After 3 attempts it disappears and I receive an error stating I do not have the rights to access the information, even though I have admin privileges throughout the entire site so I should not have this issue. This also happens in InfoPath when I try to open the initiation and association forms for edit.

I have also tried clearing the cache and restarting my machine. This is a new issue and I was able to edit these settings no problem in the past. Can anyone please help me with steps I can follow to ensure authentication to my SharePoint Online Sites

Answer (score 0):

Please check as following:

1. Use a global admin account and open [Access control page of the SharePoint admin center](https://admin.microsoft.com/sharepoint?page=accessControl&modern=true), check if you have selected **Allow access** for “Apps that don't use modern authentication”.

[image]

2. Instead of opening the site directly using SharePoint Designer 2013, go to the SharePoint site and then open SharePoint Designer 2013 from classic experience.
3. If the issue persists, use a global admin and site collection administrator account to test again.

Comment: I've tried a three suggestions... do you have any more?

Answer (score 0):

This issue appears to have resolved itself. I will mention that the issue began after a password change, attempting the same steps in the same order the next day worked.

It seems like recent password changes may be followed with a temporary loss of access to some resources in Online apps.